# Sharing data between 2 RTPs or 2 DKMs or DKM-RTP

Tags: vxworks

I'm working on a large project with multiple individual(s).
We have broken the project into multiple modules.
Individual(s) are working on separate DKMs and RTPs depending on the module they are working on. Individuals working with hardware interfaces/drivers are working on DKMs while individuals working only software components are working on RTPs.

My question is that how will individual working on different modules share data between 2 RTPs or 2 DKMs or DKM-RTP?
I was thinking of using Message Queues but unlike Linux in vxWorks their is no provision for `ftok` to generate key for message queue create API `msgQCreate`.
IPC using Sockets is not feasible due to the latency involved and real-time capabilities required.

Answer (score 0):

For time-sensitive applications, shared memory can be used. You can rely on `pmapGlobalMap` to map a fixed region in memory in the DKM:

```
uint8_t* memRegion = pmapGlobalMap(SHARED_PHYS_ADDR,
                                   SHARED_PHYS_SIZE,
                                   MMU_ATTR_SUP_RWX | MMU_ATTR_VALID);
```

Where `SHARED_PHYS_ADDR` is the physical address of the memory you want to share, `SHARED_PHYS_SIZE` its size in bytes and `MMU_ATTR_SUP_RWX | MMU_ATTR_VALID` the MMU attributes used for the memory region.

Then in the RTPs use sdOpen:

```
uint8_t* memRegion;
retVal = sdOpen(SHARED_PHYS_NAME,
                SD_LINGER,
                OM_CREATE,
                SHARED_PHYS_SIZE, 
                SHARED_PHYS_ADDR,
                SD_ATTR_RW | SD_CACHE_DEFAULT,
                (void**)&memRegion);
```

Where `SHARED_PHYS_ADDR` is the physical address of the memory you want to share, `SHARED_PHYS_SIZE` its size in bytes and `SD_ATTR_RW | SD_CACHE_DEFAULT` the MMU attributes used for the memory region. `SHARED_PHYS_NAME` is the name of the shared region.